# Is it possible to get the user IP Address for GeoLocation?

Tags: amp-html

I'm converting my site to amp-html and I need to change information on the page depending on which **country state** the user is.

The [amp-geo](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-geo/) tag only provides Contry-level geolocation info.

Knowing the IP Address I could make a JSON request to a server and get that information.

Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible via amp-list (or amp-state depending on your use case). Both enable you to determine the location based on the user's IP address and update the page accordingly. This will even work if the page is served from an AMP cache.

You can find a sample implementation on [amp.dev](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/personalization/geolocation_with_amp-list/).

Comment: The example doesn't looks like its working, and I could only get Country level info using amp-geo.

Comment: Looks like the sample backend is broken (which doesn't change the basic approach).